# Return Buffer from c++ module back to node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, buffer, node.js-addon

I'm writing c++ module for node.js and encountered the following problem.
Code:

```
void wrapMurmurHash64B(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  std::string s = getDataFromArgs(args);
  if (!s.size()) {
    return;
  }

  uint32_t seed = args[1]->NumberValue();
  uint64_t hash = MurmurHash64B(s.data(), s.size(), seed);

/*
  Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, hash);
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(num);
  return;
*/

  // as Buffer 
  Local<Object> buf;
  if (node::Buffer::New(isolate, (char*)&hash, sizeof(uint64_t)).ToLocal(&buf)) {
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(buf);
  } else {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Cannot create buffer")));
  }
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  // ...
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "murmurHash64B", wrapMurmurHash64B);
}
```

If uncomment the commented code, than the function will return the same result for every call

```
$ node
> var m = require("./build/Release/murmurhash")
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
11130111584464441000
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
11130111584464441000
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
11130111584464441000
```

The result is perfect but incorrect due to max integer size in node so we should use buffers. But there is another problem there. The first calls return incorrect and different buffers. But they should be the same

```
$ node
> var m = require("./build/Release/murmurhash")
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer bc fc a8 00 00 00 00 00>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
> m.murmurHash64B("ws2yy")
<Buffer 99 90 76 26 84 19 76 9a>
```

I suppose the error is in my understanding of c++-to-node mechanics. But I am the beginner in this scope so I need your help to make correct module.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

(char*)&hash in Buffer constructor is a referense to an automatic variable, so its value is udefined outside C++ function

Comment: so what was the solution?